# Rendering elements in a V-For loop based on specific IDX

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component, in which I only ever want to render the first element in the Array. However the length is 1, which is resulting in two renders.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <DataSolutions
      v-for="(rs, idx) in Solutions"
    >
    </DataSolutions>
 </div>
</template>
```

How does one specify the index to only render a single time? Keeping in mind that Solutions is an Array of objects.

Comment: You can filtered out the solutions array just to have only one object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question.

If you only want to show one element there why do you have a v-for?
You use v-for only if you want to show more than one element based on an array of strings/objects etc.

In any case, you can have a computed property and either filter out the objects you don't want to render

For example if you have an array called solution):

```
data() {
  return {
    solutions: [
      { id: '0001' },
      { id: '0002' },
      { id: '0003' },
    ]
  }
}
```

Then you can pick the item you want to render using computed:

```
computed: {
  solution() {
    return this.solutions[0]
  }
}
```

By doing the above, you don't need a v-for.

If you have more than one item to show then you can use again computed and filter out the items you don't want to render.